# element.append does not work with custom directive in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create dynamic table data. As we have ng-repeat for tr now i am trying one more iteration under tr for td, But html is not rendering.

```html
<tr data-ng-repeat="taskCode in taskCodeData">
    <td data-ng-repeat="headerObj in headerList" custom-data>
    </td>
</tr>
```

created custom-data directive

```
.directive('customData', function($compile, $sce) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope, element, attributes) {
            var expression = $sce.parseAsHtml($scope.headerObj.printModel);
            var getResult = function () {
                 return expression($scope);
            };

            $scope.$watch(getResult, function (newValue) {
                 console.log(newValue);
                 element.append($compile(newValue)($scope));
            });
        }
    };
});
```

in console log i am getting real value which is required. But html view is not showing any value. I think element.append function is not working.

Comment: Take a look, from docs: `append()` - Contrary to jQuery, this doesn't clone elements so will not work correctly when invoked on a jqLite object containing more than one DOM node. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `replace: true` property:

```
.directive('customData', function($compile, $sce) {
    return {
        ̶r̶e̶p̶l̶a̶c̶e̶:̶ ̶t̶r̶u̶e̶,̶
        link: function($scope, element, attributes) {
            var expression = $sce.parseAsHtml($scope.headerObj.printModel);
            var getResult = function () {
                 return expression($scope);
            };

            $scope.$watch(getResult, function (newValue) {
                 console.log(newValue);
                 element.empty();
                 element.append($compile(newValue)($scope));
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The `replace: true` property is deprecated and since the directive does not supply a template for replacement, it is not needed.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/HBAx2Gal7zud605f7Vcb?p=preview)

Sample data:

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.taskCodeData = [{x:19}];
  $scope.headerList = [{
    printModel:"data1",
  }];
  $scope.data1 = `<div>x={{taskCode.x}}</div>`;
})
```